# Find number with optional leading zeros but not starting with another digit

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to find a specific number with optional leading zeros but not starting or ending with another digit.

Sample line:

```
"123456, 123456A, A123456, A123456A, 0123456, 9123456, 1234567, ABCD0000123456 or /123456"
```

Regex I'm currently using:

```
"0*?[^1-9]123456(?!\d)"
```

Current matches:

```
 123456
A123456
A123456
0123456
0000123456
/123456
```

How to avoid the `123456`,`A123456` and `/123456` matches (want to match only `123456` from these). `A` or `ABCD` can be any other character except digits!

Desired matches:

```
123456
123456
123456
123456
0123456
0000123456
123456
```

What's the best regex for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just `0*123456`…?!

Comment: `(?<!\d)0*123456(?!\d)`, see https://regex101.com/r/VLobvG/2

Comment: Glad it does. See my demo and explanation below in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `[^1-9]` and use `(?<!\d)` negative lookbehind before `0*` pattern:

```
(?<!\d)0*123456(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VLobvG/2) and the regex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit immediately to the left is allowed
- `0*` - zero or more `0` digits
- `123456` - a specific digit string
- `(?!\d)` - no digit immediately to the right of the current location is allowed.